# Extension of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis

I have two convex functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $[0, \frac34], [\frac14,1]$ respectively such that they agree on the common domain $[\frac14, \frac34].$ How can I show that the (well defined) function $$F(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x\in[0, \frac34]$} \\
g(x), & \text{if $x\in[\frac14,1]$}
\end{cases}$$ is convex on $[0,1]$?
I tried to obtain a contradiction assuming the epigraph of $F$ is not convex, but couldn't find one. Does anyone has a good idea? I do not need a complete solution, but only a good starting.
Thank you in advance for all your helps.

Comment: The statement is not necessarily true, for example if the function value is $\infty$ on the common domain and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: @LinAlg: then each function $f, g$ failed to be convex.

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in [0,\frac{1}{4})$, $\infty$ otherwise is definitely convex.

Comment: [See this definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Convex_function_calculus) To be convex, first they must be real valued.

Comment: It says the function has to be real-valued on a convex set (that set may be empty), so there is no contradiction. See the book [Convex Analysis by R.T. Rockafellar](http://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/ConvexAnalysisRockafellar.pdf) on page 23 for another definition.

Comment: Thank you for your information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much background you can assume. One characterization of convexity is that the right-hand side derivative is increasing (a.k.a. "nondecreasing"); see *Convex Analysis* by Rockafellar. With that characterization, your result is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for useful your hint.